# Mankiewicz theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, connectedness

I'm looking for a proof of Mankiewicz theorem, which states that:

If $U, V$ are open, connected subsets of normed spaces $E, F$ respectively, then every bijective isometry $U \rightarrow V$ extends uniquely to a bijective isometry $E \rightarrow F$.

I know it's available in Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci., 20 (1972), 367–371, but it is not available online.

Could you help me?

Comment: If your library has a copy, you will find a proof for locally convex metric topological spaces in: R. Fourneau, Unimorphies of subsets of Hausdorff locally convex vector spaces. *Convexity and related combinatorial geometry* (Norman, Okla., 1980), pp. 193–202, Lecture Notes in Pure and Appl. Math., 76, Dekker, New York, 1982.